# JS Library for Widget - Snackjs, Zepto?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, prototypejs, zepto, snackjs

I have a widget which users add to their sites. I do not have control on the css and js they use. The bottom line is that it should play well with most of the libraries out there.

I have been using snackjs for jsonp, little dom manipulation and it really gets muddy while we start scaling up. Eg: it does not play well with sites using mootools.

I am looking to move to Zepto (as jQuery is too big) or similar libraries. The advantage with zepto is that most of the sites these days are using jquery and I can add zepto runtime only if jQuery is not loaded. Since the syntax is same, I am assuming that I can safely use Zepto.

However, I am not sure how can I avoid double trigger - I do not want to land up loading zepto while jQuery is also loading up. The users add the js to their site (sometimes in the head and sometimes before the end of body) - we check if jQuery is loaded (but it isn't as the user could have kept it at the bottom)... I can wait till the document is loaded (body load), put a timer to see if jQuery is loaded.. However, I want to see if there is a way to detect if jQuery is loading and how to avoid conflict with various versions of jQuery..

Is this idea even worth it? Are there better smaller js alternatives?